# How to use "li-apache-kafka-clients" in spring boot app to send large message (above 1MB) from Kafka producer?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

How to use li-apache-kafka-clients in spring boot app to send large message (above 1MB) from Kafka producer to Kafka Consumer? Below is the GitHub link of li-apache-kafka-clients:
https://github.com/linkedin/li-apache-kafka-clients

I have imported .jar file of li-apache-kafka-clients and put the below configuration for producer:

```
props.put("large.message.enabled", "true");
props.put("max.message.segment.bytes", 1000 * 1024);
props.put("segment.serializer", DefaultSegmentSerializer.class.getName());
```

and for consumer:

```
message.assembler.buffer.capacity, 
max.tracked.messages.per.partition, 
exception.on.message.dropped, 
segment.deserializer.class
```

but still getting error for large message. Please help me to solve error.

Below is my code, please let me know where I need to create LiKafkaProducer:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.boot.server}")
    private String kafkaServer;


    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfig());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<String, String>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfig() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        config.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        config.put("acks", "all");
        config.put("retries", 0);
        config.put("batch.size", 16384);
        config.put("linger.ms", 1);
        config.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);

        // The following properties are used by LiKafkaProducerImpl
        config.put("large.message.enabled", "true");
        config.put("max.message.segment.bytes", 1000 * 1024);
        config.put("segment.serializer", DefaultSegmentSerializer.class.getName());
        config.put("auditor.class", LoggingAuditor.class.getName());

        return config;
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/kafkaProducer")
public class KafkaProducerController {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaSender sender;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Student>> sendData(@RequestBody List<Student> student){

        sender.sendData(student);
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Student>>(student, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

@Service
public class KafkaSender {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaSender.class);

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Value("${kafka.topic.name}")
    private String topicName;

    public void sendData(List<Student> student) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, topicName);
        headers.put("payload", student.get(0));

        // Construct a JSONObject from a Map.
        JSONObject HeaderObject = new JSONObject(headers);
        System.out.println("\nMethod-2: Using new JSONObject() ==> " + HeaderObject);
        final String record = HeaderObject.toString();

        Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(record).setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, topicName)
                .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "Message")
                .build();

        kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, message.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement your own `ConsumerFactory` and `ProducerFactory` to create the `LiKafkaConsumer` and `LiKafkaProducer` respectively.

You should be able to subclass the default factories provided by the framework.

Comment: if possible, could you please provide a example for this? i am new to learning Kafka.

Comment: See [the reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.8.RELEASE/reference/html/#sending-messages). The `KafkaTemplate` is used to send messages; its producer is obtained from a `ProducerFactory`, usually a `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` which creates a `KafkaProducer`. You would need to provide the template with your own factory that creates the `LiKafkaProducer` instead.

Comment: I am trying to create LiKafkaProducer but getting errors. below is my code which I'm doing in config file but how can I send to LiKafkaProducer. please help
`
@Bean
 public ProducerFactory<Integer, String> producerFactory() {
  LiKafkaProducer<String, String> liKafkaProducer = new LiKafkaProducerImpl<>(producerConfig());
  return liKafkaProducer;
 }
 
 @Bean
 public KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> kafkaTemplate() {
  return new KafkaTemplate<Integer, String>(producerFactory());
 }
`

Comment: Don't put code in comments. Too hard to read. Edit the question instead and comment that you have done so. You also need to show the exception. Your producer factory doesn't look right at all. The bean is a factory but the method returns a producer.

Comment: I have edited the question with code. please let me know, where i need to create LiKafkaProducer.

Comment: `return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfig());` You need your own implementation of ProducerFactory. The template calls `this.producerFactory.createProducer();` where you need to return a LiKafkaProducer

Comment: I tried to create my own ProducerFactory but it didn't work, I think I am doing it wrong way. could you please provide the example to implement own ProducerFactory instead of DefaultKafkaProducerFactory? or is there another way to handle large message in Kafka?